# Can the payer of my cell bill listen to my calls?

Tags: privacy, mobile

I am not an IT person so I'd need a simply-worded answer.
I'm considering getting a smart phone, and someone else would be paying the bill, someone I don't necessarily trust.  I'd like to know: would they be able to listen to my calls, and if so, how difficult would it be for them to do so?  (They don't have much tech knowledge either.)

Comment: This is not an InfoSec question - ask your cell company.

Comment: **Note:** They'd be able to get a list of numbers you've called and number that have called you (as well as SMS messages).

Comment: It depends... If this someone else is an employer then maybe if they can install certain software on your phone. If you are concerned about it then don't get a smart phone till you can afford to pay for it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Tapping a cell phone is doable, but very difficult, especially for someone who has little tech knowledge, and providers generally do not give the capability to listen in on specific calls either. The bill may show the duration of the call and who the call was made to/from, but generally they wouldn't be able to listen in. Consider each cell phone on the plan as a separate connection. The payer of the bill would have to somehow get onto your cell connection and then have a way to listen in on your calls. That's something way to difficult for the non-tech savvy to accomplish. I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they can. If they pay the bill, they maybe have enrolled your phone to an MDM software. This give them the ability to install a program to your phone to record all the phone calls and store it locally as files. Then, as they are admins of your device, they can download those files and listen to them.

They could also record voice conversation by opening the built-in mic, take photos, videos, know your location (gps) and so on.

However, because almost all countries have rules regarding the protection of personal information, doing all this stuff is against the law, and they could be in big trouble.

But again, from the technical point, a smart phone is perfect spying device.

Comment: We should be careful to say that paying your bill does not *necessarily* give them the admin / account passwords to your physical device. Those things don't have to be connected.